# Yii: How can I give all dropDownList the same width?

Tags: php, yii

I need to give all dropDownList in _form and _search the same width. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is include the following css at the top of either partial.

```
<style> select { width: 8em } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      echo CHtml::dropDownList("id", $arr_bit, $list, array('id' => "id",
                    'onchange' => 'send(this.id, this.value)',
                    'style'=>'height: auto; width: auto;'
                            )
                     );
```